# Progress of a Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

Will it be possible to show progress for

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameter, encoding: .JSON)
 .responseJSON { response in
 // Do your stuff
}
```

I get my images/documents as a base64 string then I convert it as files in mobile

Can I show a progress bar with percentage?

I am using Alamofire, Swift 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you monitor progress in Alamofire is using the `progress` closure on a `Request`. More details on usage can be found in the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-a-file-wprogress). While that example in the README demonstrates usage on a download request, it still works on a data request as well.

The one important note is that you do not always get perfect reporting back from the server for a data request. The reason is that the server does not always report an accurate content length before streaming the data. If the content length is unknown, the progress closure will be called, but the `totalExpectedBytesToRead` will always be `-1`.

In this situation, you can only report accurate progress if you know the approximate size of the data being downloaded. You could then use your approximate number in conjunction with the `totalBytesRead` value to compute an estimated download progress value.

Comment: as I understand, I cannot show an  progress for .request rite?

Comment: Depends on the type of data you are getting back. For example, if you download image data from something like S3 using `request`, you will probably be able to accurately report the progress because the server will tell you what the `totalExpectedBytes` is. If you are hitting a JSON web service that computes the response on-the-fly, it may not compute how large the response will be before sending it back. In that case you would NOT be able to accurately report progress.

Comment: I am using the later one, I think. So I think its best to show a loader and then wait till the request is completed 
Thanks for your help @cnoon

Comment: You bet dude. If you think the answer is sufficient, then you should upvote and mark as the answer. 

Comment: @cnoon is there a way to use already loaded part of data in the progress handler?

Answer (score 6):

**Alamofire 4.0 and Swift 4.x**

```
func startDownload(audioUrl:String) -> Void {
    let fileUrl = self.getSaveFileUrl(fileName: audioUrl)
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        return (fileUrl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    Alamofire.download(audioUrl, to:destination)
        .downloadProgress { (progress) in
            self.surahNameKana.text = (String)(progress.fractionCompleted)
        }
        .responseData { (data) in
            // at this stage , the downloaded data are already saved in fileUrl
            self.surahNameKana.text = "Completed!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To make a download with progress for Swift 2.x users with Alamofire >= 3.0:

```
let url = "https://httpbin.org/stream/100" // this is for example..
let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

Alamofire.download(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL,destination:destination)
                .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                    // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
                    // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.         
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        // Here you can update your progress object
                        print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
                        print("Progress on main queue: \(Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead))")
                    }
                }
                .response { request, _, _, error in
                    print("\(request?.URL)")  // original URL request
                    if let error = error {
                        let httpError: NSError = error
                        let statusCode = httpError.code
                    } else { //no errors
                        let filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
                        print("File downloaded successfully: \(filePath)")
                    }
            }
```

Comment: I used progress in alert and want to use this in the alamo fire but didn't work for me here is the link of that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070516/progress-view-in-alamo-fire-will-not-update-when-downloading-file-in-swift-3