# Tracking progress in Alamofire Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I wanna know it is possible to show progress for request. I convert my images to base64 string and send it to my server with parameter. Is there a way to track it's progress? I wanna try something like that.But I cannot add progress section in my Alamofire.request. Is there something that I am missing?

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameter, encoding: .JSON)
.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
 // track progress here
 }
.responseJSON { response in
// Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827438/progress-of-a-alamofire-request

Comment: Yes, but I know the approximate size of my data and I wanna show progress.

Comment: edit your question with more details regarding your problem and what you want to achieve. As suggested, this looks like a duplicate. do you mean you want to update UI?

Comment: Nah, I am trying to add progress section in my Alamofire.request. Guess I am missing something. Btw I just updated my question. @Soroush

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33873721/8294374

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think the current version of Alamofire uses `downloadProgress` instead of `progress`:

```swift
Alamofire.request(/* ... */).downloadProgress { progress in
  progress.fractionCompleted // value between 0 and 1
}
.responseJSON { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I tried this but download progress fractionCompleted always being 0 with totalUnitCount being -1. What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in





        }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in

            switch result {

            case .success(let upload, _, _):



                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in



                    // Here you get the progress

                    print(Progress.fractionCompleted)




                })


                upload.responseJSON { response in






            case .failure( _ ):



            }

        })
```